# Why is my VBA Excel Range.Find for 1st empty cell failing at row 64

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have code that finds the first empty cell to input data.  It was working fine until the Excel spreadsheet reached row 63.  At that point, the line 63 was written over every time new data was saved.  I was able to fix this by changing my find+1 to find+2, not a good solution.  I want to know what caused my code to stop working and fix that instead of adding 1 every so many rows.  Any help would be immensely appreciated!  My original code is below.

```vb
Private Sub B_Save_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
  
   'Make Sheet1 active
   Sheet1.Activate
  
   'Determine emptyRow
   emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1  'this is where I changed 1 to 2 to get the code working again.
    
   'here is where I load the data from the form to the empty spreadsheet row
   
    'this forces the worksheet to save so the new data will show up right away
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
                
    'now that data is saved, clear fields so we can enter additional applications
    'set all the values to "" or False and reset focus

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you use CountA() then any empty cell in your data will impact the result.  `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).offset(1)` is the first empty cell at the end of your data.  If your data can have empty cells in ColA though, neither of those approaches are reliable if you need to avoid possibly overwriting data.

Comment: What was causing the last row of data to be overwritten when there were no empty cells in column A prior to the last row of data?

Comment: How can we know that without you showing us the code that did that?

Comment: I did show the code up above.

Comment: `'here is where I load the data from the form to the empty spreadsheet row` is a comment, not code.  The only thing you show is how you obtain `emptyRow`

Comment: The code I posted would bring me to the last row and that row would be written over.  The variable emptyRow held the 1st empty cell in column A until I hit 63 rows.  At that point, emptyRow held the row number 63.  That is where I am having the issue.  The code I posted worked until the spreadsheet held 63 rows of data.

Comment: Once I changed the +1 to +2 in the line emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1, the code worked fine again, writing to the first empty row.

Comment: What would cause that to happen?

Comment: I'm capable of following the code you posted, but once again I'm not capable of determining what went wrong when the part you *didn't post* got executed...

Comment: why did my original code get edited by Brax?  It no longer shows what my function does.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment above:

```vb
Private Sub B_Save_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
  
    'first empty cell below any data in ColA
    emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'if you need to be sure, check for any content in that row
    Do While Application.CountA(Sheet1.Rows(emptyRow)) > 0
        emptyRow = emptyRow + 1 'next row down
    Loop
    
    'rest of code
    
End Sub
```